# Does "await" respawn a task if it has already been .Start()-ed?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

If I have the following:

```
// a:
// returns a task, then starts and joins it with "await" keyword
var resultA = await GetBigTask();

// b:
// gets a Task<T>, launches it with Start(), then joins it with "await"
var myBigTask = GetBigTask();
myBigTask.Start();
var resultB = await myBigTask;
```

Just to be clear, are my comments there correct?

Using the "await" keyword on a Task that has NOT been started (like an anonymous task returned from `GetBigTask()`) will Start it and then join it.  Using the "await" keyword on a Task that has already been .Start()-ed will NOT start a second instance of it, instead it will join the existing one?

So if I have many big tasks that are all totally independent of one another, it is ALWAYS beneficial to me to launch them like "c", instead of "d"?

```
// c:
var taskA = GetTaskA();
var taskB = GetTaskB();
var taskC = GetTaskC();

// they are all launched in parallel
taskA.Start(); taskB.Start(); taskC.Start();

// then joined together at the end
await taskA; await taskB; await taskC;

// d:
await GetTaskA();
await GetTaskB();  // not launched until GetTaskA() concludes!
await GetTaskC();  // not launched until GetTaskA() AND B concludes!
```

Is all this correct?  If not, how do I achieve "c", that is, launch multiple (independent) tasks at once, and await them all later?

Comment: If `GetBigTask()` returns the same `Task`, then `await`-ing it will wait until it is complete.  Whether or not you choose c or d depends on if you want to wait or not ("fire and forget").  If you want to await them all use [`Task.WaitAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your question, it's impossible to know for sure what would happen with the code you did show. That said, there are at least a couple of misconceptions apparent in your question:

> - Misconception #1: `await` starts a task.
> - Misconception #2: `await` joins a thread.

If you use `await` to wait for a task that has not been started, it does not itself start the task. It will wait forever, unless *somewhere else* you have some code that starts the task.

As far as the "join" goes, that word is typically used to describe an operation where the current thread *waits* for some other thread or task. That's exactly the opposite of what `await` does (yes, I realize the nomenclature is a bit confusing). When your execution reaches an `await` statement, the currently executing method returns at that point, allowing the thread to continue executing. If and when the awaitable being awaited completes, execution will *resume* immediately after the `await` statement.

But until that happens, execution in that thread isn't blocked (or "joined").

The `await` statement has some other useful behaviors: when the operation being awaited completes, if it does so successfully, the result value will be retrieved and returned by the `await` expression. And if the operation is unsuccessful and instead throws an exception, the exception will be unpacked and rethrown by the `await` expression.

In your example, if `GetBigTask()` literally returns a task object that hasn't yet been started, then simply using `await GetBigTask()` won't do anything useful because the wait will never complete. If the task object *has* already been started, then calling `myBigTask.Start()` will throw an exception.

Typically, asynchronous methods that return task objects will return those objects in an already-running state. So it's possible that your question reflects a third misconception:

> - Misconception #3: methods like `GetBigTask()`, `GetTaskA()`, etc. return a task object that hasn't yet been started.

Granted, without a complete code example it's not possible to say for sure. But assuming those methods were written by someone familiar with the usual asynchronous idioms in C#, there's no need to call `Start()` on the returned object.

If that's in fact the case, then it is sufficient to do the following:

```
var taskA = GetTaskA();
var taskB = GetTaskB();
var taskC = GetTaskC();

await taskA;
await taskB;
await taskC;
```

All of the tasks will have been returned in the already-running state by the `GetTask...()` methods. Calling `await` in sequence will handle the completion of each task in sequence, having the effect of not continuing the rest of the method until all three tasks are complete.

Comment: So just to clarify, if your final example code, tasks A, B, and C can all be in the "Start()-ed" state at the same time?  And if instead we had called `await GetTaskA(); await GetTaskB(); await GetTaskC();` then A must complete before B can begin, and B must complete before C can begin?

Comment: @andy: that all depends on what those methods do. Typically, the method that returns the task is what starts it and if so, yes...if you put the method call directly into the `await` expression (as in your comment), then each subsequent task won't be started until the previous one completes. I cannot guarantee this though, because it depends on what those methods do. It is possible (though unlikely) that they simply return task objects representing tasks that were already started previously by some other operation and are already running concurrently.